# jQuery button element moves when browser resized

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a div element that has some jQuery appended to it to give it a bounce effect. The element is positioned absolutely with its parent relative. When you resize the browser, the child element moves and not kept central when re-sizing until you stop re-sizing the browser.

Can some give me some advice please on how to stop this occurring?

HTML

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="test">
            <div id="buttonbounce"></div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Script

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    function doAnimation() {
        $("#buttonbounce").effect( "bounce", {times:3}, 1000, doAnimation);
    }
    doAnimation();
});
```

Please see my codepen to see it in action

[view codepen](http://codepen.io/hassanruby/pen/RWWrPR)

Comment: It keeps the central position, you just have to wait a little bit

Comment: Hint: with `jquery-ui.min.js` http://jsfiddle.net/x1kLw28j/ and without `jquery-ui.min.js` http://jsfiddle.net/x1kLw28j/1/

Answer (score 0):

You need to apply the margin:0 auto; to the containing div instead of to the buttonbounce. This fixes it.

```
.test {position:relative;
      margin:0 auto;
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;}

#buttonbounce {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative
    top:30px;    
    background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/26037.png);
    background-size: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

please try this one:

```
.test {position:relative;
      margin:0 auto;
      width: 45px;
      height: 45px;}

#buttonbounce {
    width: 45px;
    height: 45px;
    position: relative
    top:30px;    
    background-image: url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/26037.png);
    background-size: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    } url(http://cdn.flaticon.com/png/256/26037.png);
    background-size: 45px;
    cursor: pointer;
    }
```

[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ivinraj/x1kLw28j/3/)